# Silverlight ListBox: How to find out if user is currently dragging the scrollbar slider?

Tags: silverlight, listbox, slider, scrollbar

Scenario: I have a ListBox, containing a WrapPanel from the Silverlight Toolkit as ItemsPanel:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxFaelle">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

This ListBox gets populated automatically with the results of a RIA service call every 60 seconds. While the application is waiting for the LoadOperation to complete, it displays the standard BusyIndicator that is part of the Silverlight Business Application template.

This works fine as long as the user is not dragging the scrollbar slider of the ListBox when the Timer Event fires.

Problem: If the user is dragging the scrollbar slider when the BusyIndicator is being displayed, the scrollbar doesn’t work anymore, afterwards. It looks like the mouse pointer remains captured to the slider even if the left mouse button is released. I assume this happens because the BusyIndicator temporarily takes away the focus from the slider while it is being dragged.

Question: Is there a way to find out if the scrollbar slider of the ListBox is currently being pushed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no status/property to find out if the slider is being pushed.

That said you could try to keep track of it yourself by handling [MouseLeftButtonDown and Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) events but you might have to consider other events as well depending on your scenario (mouse wheel?)

> MouseLeftButtonUp Occurs when the left mouse button is released (or the tip of the stylus is removed from the tablet) while the mouse (or the stylus) is over a UIElement (or while a UIElement holds mouse capture). (Inherited from UIElement.)

It might also be possible to solve this the other way around by releasing the MouseCapture (if that is causing the problem) by using [ReleaseMouseCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Again, it depends on what you want to happen from the user's point of view: skip the loading of the data (this is what I would prefer because I do not like the content to be changing when I am scrolling) or reset the listbox and scroll to the top (ugly in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks, Erno. I agree that it would best to simply skip the loading of data while the user is scrolling. Unfortunately, Silverlight does not support the IsMouseCaptured property. I also tried ReleaseMouseCapture(), but I failed to find the reference to the appropriate control. How can I find the actual scrollbar in the control hierarchy?

In the meantime I found out that the same problem arises with the GridSplitter control. I think I better don't use the BusyIndicator at all.

Comment: Ah yes, silverlight... sorry I keep messing up reading the help on Silverlight and WPF. I suspect the busy indicator as well. To find the scrollbar I am afraid you'll have to search the template.